# Есть ли другой рецепт для Pillow по наложению изображений?

Tags: python-3.6, pillow

Мне надо наложить одно изображение на другое.

Во многих местах Интернета натыкаюсь на пример кода наложения изображений по маске, например [здесь](https://djbook.ru/examples/53/)

Заставить работать код не смог, сколько не мучался. Картинку то он пишет, но ожидаемого наложения добиться не удалось. Получал, например 4 картинки image, но без наложения. 
В примере смущает шаг в цикле.
пытался его варьировать, но в лучшем случае удавалось добиться только белой картинки.

Если готового рабочего скрипта нет, то проще наверное воспользоваться руководством [здесь](https://auth0.com/blog/image-processing-in-python-with-pillow/#Pasting-an-Image-onto-Another-Image) и написать свой скрипт.

P.S. Да, пример с наложением по маске для водяных знаков. Наверное не мой случай. Хотя наложение на прозрачный фон было бы желательно.

Comment: Написал все-таки свой скрипт и быстрее и надежнее.
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

img_base = Image.open("a1.png")
if img_base.mode != 'RGBA':
    img_base = img_base.convert('RGBA')
else:
    img_base = img_base.copy()

img_top = Image.open("a1.png")
if img_top.mode != 'RGBA':
    img_top = img_top.convert('RGBA')
else:
    img_top = img_top.copy()

img_copy = img_base.copy()

position = (0,0)

img_copy.paste(img_top, position,img_top)
img_copy.save("example_past.png", "PNG", quality=75)

P.S. Вариант для логотипа в комменты не помещается))

Comment: Попалось описание микса цветов RGBA, т.е. можно доработать существенно данный скрипт и налагаемое изображение не будет полностью перекрывать базовое. Получим просвечивание. Сделать можно, но мне сейчас это не нужно))